# Diagnose high CPU on seemingly idle powershell session

Tags: powershell, debug, high-cpu-usage

I'm finding Powershell is using 20% cpu after a bunch of scripts have run.

The script is made up of a bunch of AzureRM modules, posh-git and vssetup modules and a bunch of custom modules (none of which should have any loops - unless there is a bug).

Suspecting one of the modules is in an infinite loop I unloaded each module. However unloading all the modules, the CPU is still high.

Using `procmon` I can see:

`GetMetaDataPublicInterfaceFromInternal` in the threads.

Any suggestions on the next step to diagnose why the high CPU is still occurring?

It doesn't seem to happen on a fresh powershell session (with `posh-git` loaded).

Comment: You may want to start by debugging with `Set-PSDebug -Trace 1`.

Comment: Thanks @root, in theory I don't have any scripts running to debug as the scripts have already finished (in theory). Unless Set-PSDebug does other things (I haven't used it much), just debugging in ISE?

Comment: I see now, everything I run with Set-PSDebug is output to the console, thanks for the tip.

Comment: I wondered if it was a script with a background job, but Get-Job doesn't show anything. Also Get-ScheduledTask (and then stopping everything) doesn't help either.

Comment: Tough to say without combing through each script. Using `Set-PSDebug` may be helpful the next time you run the scripts. If you have an infinite loop, it will be obvious when looking at the console with debugging on. Otherwise, you're right to try procmon.